# How do I summarise in years from a specific date i.e. max(close_date) to the corresponding date in one year previous periods of time in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write R code to summarize count and median amounts of a date variable, and a dollar amount variable in my data frame. The summarize part is not the issue, my issue is in trying to group_by time periods to then summarize. I understand the distinction between a time period and a time duration. I am interested in time periods, in this particular case I want to summarize in years from a specific date i.e. max(close_date) to the corresponding date in one year previous periods of time, as in 2022-02-6 to 2021-02-06 to 2020-02-06 and so on. The data frame goes back about 30 months in total, so there is two full years of data to summarize.

The code I wrote here groups by the calendar year, and not what I need;

```
> sum_closed_date_yr <- scrubbed_data01 %>%
+   group_by(time_period = year(close_date)) %>%
+   summarize(close_count = (close_date = n()), med_close_price = median(close_price, na.rm = TRUE))

> sum_closed_date_yr

# A tibble: 5 × 3
  time_period close_count med_close_price
        <dbl>       <int>           <dbl>
1        2019          31          570000
2        2020          80          661250
3        2021         104          930750
4        2022           9         1010000
5          NA           8               0
```

I am very new to coding in R, I am a real estate appraiser not a statwhizzician. I have taken 23 DataCamp tutorials in R, so I have a newbie working knowledge of R. I have searched through multiple SO posts on summarizing by date, but can not find what I am specifically looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you - Joe

Second try, I selected just the two of many variables

```
scrubbed_data01 %>%
+   select(close_date, close_price) %>%
+   dput()
structure(list(close_date = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 19039, 19038, 
19034, 19024, 19020, 19016, 19013, 18999, 18989, 18976, 18969, 
18969, 18968, 18955, 18955, 18954, 18953, 18953, 18949, 18948, 
18943, 18940, 18936, 18934, 18933, 18929, 18922, 18921, 18921, 
18921, 18918, 18915, 18912, 18908, 18908, 18907, 18906, 18905, 
18900, 18900, 18899, 18897, 18897, 18897, 18891, 18891, 18890, 
18887, 18880, 18879, 18878, 18878, 18873, 18873, 18873, 18869, 
18866, 18866, 18851, 18850, 18844, 18836, 18836, 18831, 18830, 
18822, 18821, 18821, 18815, 18810, 18806, 18802, 18796, 18795, 
18789, 18786, 18782, 18781, 18781, 18780, 18779, 18775, 18775, 
18774, 18761, 18761, 18753, 18752, 18747, 18746, 18746, 18740, 
18739, 18737, 18729, 18718, 18715, 18705, 18704, 18701, 18695, 
18689, 18683, 18677, 18655, 18652, 18648, 18646, 18640, 18634, 
18633, 18631, 18619, 18613, 18611, 18590, 18585, 18579, 18576, 
18569, 18569, 18569, 18563, 18558, 18557, 18557, 18556, 18554, 
18549, 18544, 18540, 18540, 18533, 18519, 18519, 18519, 18514, 
18514, 18513, 18507, 18502, 18502, 18501, 18501, 18499, 18495, 
18492, 18492, 18491, 18488, 18484, 18472, 18466, 18464, 18459, 
18459, 18453, 18451, 18450, 18445, 18443, 18442, 18423, 18422, 
18411, 18401, 18400, 18397, 18397, 18397, 18396, 18387, 18386, 
18366, 18361, 18360, 18340, 18338, 18331, 18317, 18313, 18302, 
18297, 18289, 18283, 18283, 18277, 18274, 18271, 18271, 18269, 
18263, 18261, 18261, 18261, 18260, 18250, 18247, 18239, 18208, 
18200, 18199, 18197, 18194, 18190, 18185, 18185, 18180, 18179, 
18177, 18177, 18176, 18170, 18169, 18156, 18155, 18152, 18151, 
18142, 18142, 18138, 18137, 18136, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19044), class = "Date"), 
    close_price = c(0, 0, 0, 1150001, 940000, 1253000, 979000, 
    881000, 1010000, 1060000, 1100000, 1070000, 1025000, 755000, 
    740000, 930000, 1250000, 990000, 930000, 931500, 975000, 
    950000, 850000, 865000, 921000, 790000, 778000, 935000, 1270000, 
    970000, 1061500, 960000, 1015000, 1100000, 1082000, 880000, 
    1000000, 1140000, 950000, 852000, 1045000, 795000, 950000, 
    950000, 880000, 850000, 945000, 949500, 1220000, 1015000, 
    899000, 1100000, 805000, 868000, 1102000, 1015000, 923000, 
    810000, 890000, 826000, 1140000, 970000, 830000, 790000, 
    1151000, 835500, 1080000, 870000, 1049000, 985000, 962000, 
    926000, 1008888, 950000, 810000, 760000, 955000, 930000, 
    985000, 1210000, 878000, 950000, 855000, 930000, 960000, 
    1180000, 980000, 960000, 898000, 1100000, 1215000, 885000, 
    985000, 880000, 1100000, 810000, 1210000, 810000, 970700, 
    1010000, 800000, 850000, 849000, 770000, 925000, 930000, 
    875000, 755000, 675000, 875500, 715000, 837000, 747000, 805000, 
    785000, 801200, 900000, 800000, 610000, 720000, 730000, 700000, 
    695000, 720000, 750000, 860000, 915000, 787000, 785000, 710000, 
    735000, 620000, 788000, 780000, 780000, 645000, 700000, 686000, 
    686000, 745000, 745000, 605000, 730000, 625000, 625000, 685000, 
    731000, 715000, 695000, 710000, 700000, 575000, 561000, 590000, 
    595000, 720500, 670000, 711000, 645000, 595000, 700000, 545000, 
    695000, 531000, 581000, 518000, 645000, 562500, 530000, 640000, 
    643000, 680000, 700000, 540000, 630000, 658000, 675000, 525000, 
    600000, 664500, 590000, 569595, 620500, 555000, 585000, 630000, 
    639900, 515000, 475000, 670000, 610000, 524888, 550000, 520000, 
    650000, 500000, 500000, 540000, 608000, 575000, 570000, 639900, 
    645000, 648500, 635000, 530000, 655000, 520000, 555000, 542500, 
    515000, 620000, 580140, 535000, 638888, 540000, 590000, 535000, 
    497500, 505000, 675000, 545000, 640000, 555000, 630000, 590000, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 985000)), row.names = c(NA, 232L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: I edited my original question to include data requested by someone, but it would not post. The web site refused to post my edit until I let time pass about an hour or so. I have no idea why. confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new variable to assign the year to your desired period:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(period_year =  case_when(close_date < "2019-02-06" ~ 2018,
                                        close_date >= "2019-02-06" & close_date < "2020-02-06" ~ 2019,
                                        close_date >= "2020-02-06" & close_date < "2021-02-06" ~ 2020,
                                        close_date >= "2021-02-06" & close_date < "2022-02-06" ~ 2021,
                                        close_date >= "2022-02-06" & close_date < "2023-02-06" ~ 2022)) %>% 
group_by(time_period = period_year) %>%
summarize(close_count = (close_date = n()), med_close_price = median(close_price, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Hi Bloxx did you write the above code or were the equal or greater than & less than dates calculated. I see case_when() function allows you to vectorise multiple if_else() statements. I see that working for a few dates like years but when I want to do the same with three month differences it would get a bit tedious.

Comment: I wrote them. As you only have a few "periods", this is a simple solution.